# could we create Virtual host for modules in Zend framework1.11

Tags: zend-framework, virtualhost

currently I have a `zend 1.xx` project with three modules `module1`, `module2`, `module3`.

My requirement is to create separate virtual host for each module.

Like if we type `http://module1` is should load module1, and we type `http://module2` then it should load `module2` of the project.

What should be the `DocumentRoot` value in virtual host for modules other then default.

For default module `.../project/public` works fine, but not for other modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely not use virtual hosts to do that, unless you actually split your codebase per module (meaning having a copy of the code with only module1, module2 or module3).

What you can do very easily is disable the [default routes](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.default-routes) (which will remove access to your app altogether I believe, I suppose you haven't defined your own routes), then create a [Route chain](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.chain) that chains a [route hostname](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.hostname) and a route that looks like the default one.

So:

1. disable the default route
2. create a route just like the default one without module
3. create 3 routes hostname (one per domain)
4. create 3 chains that have a route hostname (3.) and the default route (2.)

Comment: thanks for your reply. would it require virtual hosts setup?

Comment: Not really, it depends of your current setup basically... If your current virtualhost accepts the different domains, no need to change; if your current setup has no virtualhost, all the traffic goes through this app so no extra setup... Really depends on your setup though...

Comment: Following is the code used for my "beat" module and still picking default module layout -  `$hostnameAdminRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname('beat', array('module' => 'beat'));
        $router
        ->addRoute('beat' , $hostnameAdminRoute->chain(new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':controller/:action/*',   array('controller'=>'index', 'action'=>'index'))))`    What could be the reason?

Comment: also I have added above code into Default module's Bootstrap.php file only.

Comment: Which url are you targeting? I can see in your code a route hostname, but no host in it...

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this by using following set of code into application.ini file -

```
; This piece of code used for rounting usoc host to default module 
resources.router.routes.plain.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.plain.abstract = true
resources.router.routes.plain.route = "/:controller/:action"
resources.router.routes.plain.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.plain.defaults.action = "index"
```

Above code if for default module.

```
; This piece of code used for rounting beat host to beat module
resources.router.routes.beat.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
resources.router.routes.beat.route = "beat"
resources.router.routes.beat.defaults.module = "beat"
resources.router.routes.beat.chains.index.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.beat.chains.index.route = ":controller/:action/*"
resources.router.routes.beat.chains.index.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.beat.chains.index.defaults.action = "index"
```

Above code if for beat  module and host name is also beat